# Passing a repeated block to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I have a form with multiple "li" elements that contain form fields, where the only thing that varies is one word in multiple placee. Example:

```
li
  = f.label :answer_tax, 'Tax'
  = f.text_field :answer_tax,
  'ng-model' => 'Form.tax',
  'ng-pattern' => '{{pattern}}',
  'ng-focus' => 'initFields(Form.tax)',
  'ng-blur' => 'updateScore(Form.tax, "tax")'

li
  = f.label :answer_chase, 'Chase'
  = f.text_field :answer_chase,
  'ng-model' => 'Form.chase',
  'ng-pattern' => '{{pattern}}',
  'ng-focus' => 'initFields(Form.chase)',
  'ng-blur' => 'updateScore(Form.chase, "chase")'
```

I would like to create a partial that takes each word from an array and generates the form fields. Where is the best place to do this (helper?) and how would I go about doing it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it in the view, you don't even need to use a partial if you feel this is simpler (i've assumed you're using HAML? If I'm right, you should have % on the li tag?):

```
- %w{ tax chase }.each do |field_name|
  %li
    = f.label "answer_#{field_name}".to_sym, field_name.capitalize
    = f.text_field "answer_#{field_name}".to_sym,
    'ng-model' => "Form.#{field_name}",
    'ng-pattern' => '{{pattern}}',
    'ng-focus' => "initFields(Form.#{field_name})',
    'ng-blur' => "updateScore(Form.#{field_name}, \"#{field_name}\")"
```

Comment: That is phenomenal. I'm using slim but it's basically the same. Thanks so much for your help.